# Would Lync Server SDK or UCMA enable me to implement additional authentication for conference?

Tags: c#, .net, lync, ucma

I would like to create additional authentication for the conference call.

Scenario would look something like this:

1. Client calls the conference
2. In chat window he is asked for some secret that is authenticating him using 3rd party server
3. Client after successful authentication is allowed to join the conference.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Documentation maybe?

Comment: I found [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Communications-Development-Microsoft-Programmer/dp/0470939036) to be a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutly do this using the UCMA SDK.

If the UCMA application creates the conferences, and is the only conference leader, and the settings of the conference are such that all particiants must join the lobby first and be expressly admitted into the conference, then the bot could be notified of users attempting to join the conference (they would go to the lobby, not the actual conference) and could then start a IM conversation with them to validate them. Once the bot is happy it could then invite them to the conference. Of course, you could also add some participants as attendees - which would mean they could join the conference automatically without being challenged.

Have a look at the conference lobby, meeting setup properties, creating scheduled conferences, and the events which are raised once a conference is created.

The following MSDN sample might be of use:

[Schedule and Join a Conference (QuickStart)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh364917.aspx)

Hope that helps.